# TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED method spends transaction time of the suspended transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, ejb

I have a method that does heavy operations (file handling) that does not need a transaction but is inside one and generates timeouts. I don't have the option to refactor the code or to raise the default transaction timeout. I have tried using `TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED` in the file handler method to temporarily suspend the transaction but it keeps counting time while it is suspended and keeps giving me timeout.

Is this way of working correct? When the transaction is suspended, is the transaction time still spent?

I have made the following example approximation with the same problem.
Code:

```
@Slf4j
@Stateless
public class Foo1 {

    @Inject
    Foo2 foo2;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @TransactionTimeout(value= 10, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void saveWith10secondsTimeout() {
        log.info("Start Foo1");
        Foo entity = new entity();
        em.persist(entity);
        foo2.threadSleep15seconds();
        log.info("End Foo1");
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class Foo2 {
    public void threadSleep15seconds() {
        log.info("Start Foo2");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        log.info("End Foo2");
    }
}
```

Controller call:

```
@Inject
Foo1 foo1;

@GET
@Path("/foo-not-supported")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public Response testNotSupported() {
    log.info("Start testNotSupported");
    foo1.saveWith10secondsTimeout();
    return Response.status(OK).build();
}
```

Logs:

```
15:00:30,867 INFO  [com.FooController] (default task-1) Start testNotSupported
15:00:30,868 INFO  [com.Foo1] (default task-1) Start Foo1
15:00:30,883 INFO  [com.Foo2] (default task-1) Start Foo2
15:00:40,867 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:-441cac6:64394e3c:382 in state  RUN
15:00:40,877 INFO  [org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
15:00:40,881 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:-441cac6:64394e3c:382
15:00:45,884 INFO  [com.Foo2] (default task-1) End Foo2
15:00:45,884 INFO  [com.Foo1] (default task-1) End Foo1
15:00:45,884 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-1) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:-441cac6:64394e3c:382
15:00:45,887 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component Foo1 for method public void com.Foo1.saveWith10secondsTimeout(): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:-441cac6:64394e3c:382 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
```

Comment: I would hope so as that transaction can be holding locks that prevent other transactions from completing. It isn't best to keep transactions open for long periods, and just being able to disable a transaction does nothing to release its locks and let other processes continue. What is your purpose in suspending the transaction exactly?

Comment: @Chris The purpose of suspending the transaction was to avoid the timeout, some of the processes that handle files are close to five minutes (in the example it would be the threadSleep15seconds method) and they generate a timeout in the transaction but the file operation is carried out correctly. The idea was to use NOT_SUPPORTED so that this time would not be added to the transaction time but either I am not using it correctly or it does not work like that and I will have no choice but to either increase the transaction timeout or refactor the code.

Comment: When using TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED, ongoing transactions are suspended during method execution and resumed upon completion. The transaction timeout still runs, so if it expires before the method completes, the transaction is rolled back. In this case, the transaction is rolled back before the method completes because Foo2.threadSleep15seconds() takes more than the 10-second timeout value set for Foo1.saveWith10secondsTimeout(). You can increase the timeout value or handle the file operations asynchronously or in smaller chunks if you can't modify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction timeout means that the transaction may be rolled back if it is still active when the period has elapsed. Suspending the transaction has no effect on the timeout (since that would contradict the purpose of setting the timeout).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some design issue here.

`Foo2.threadSleep15seconds()` seems to be simulating the long-running file process that you are talking about.  How tightly that file processing is associated with the ongoing DB transaction?

If you can have some kind of state management separately, what you can do is, as part of the `Foo1.saveWith10secondsTimeout()`, you just insert a record in a DB table that file processing is `pending`. And return immediately, so that the transaction is not held up for a long period.

Have a separate thread (asynchronous execution of `Foo2.threadSleep15seconds()`) to process all the files to be processed by all the requests made to `Foo1.saveWith10secondsTimeout()`.  That thread (or a pool of threads) will continue to process files and change the status of those files in the DB Table from `pending` to `done` or `error` based on the result and then trigger the next process based on the result.

But if a single transaction is held up till the time all the files are processed, it would definitely lock up some other activities elsewhere.